# SQL Server: get current month and previous months

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, stored-procedures, group-by

I have a table with a column `dateE` that is formatted as `nvarchar(20)` and contains dates in the format yyyy-mm-dd. 
The below stored procedure fetches all records from this table with dateE from Apr 2014:

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT      cat,
                COUNT(*) AS groupCount
    FROM        Log_PE 
    WHERE       dateE LIKE '2014-04%'
    GROUP BY    cat
    ORDER BY    groupCount desc, cat
END
```

How can I change this so that I don't have to hard-code the date and instead it always uses the current year and month for this ?

In addition, I would like to use the same stored procedure to also fetch the same data from the previous three months (in this case Jan, Feb, March 2014) so that in the end I have a ranking like in my example but for each of the above months.

Can anyone here help me with this ?

Many thanks in advance, Tim.

Comment: Why you keep the date in varchar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of comparing strings, compare dates. Try this:

```
SELECT      cat, COUNT(*) AS groupCount
FROM        Log_PE 
WHERE       CONVERT(DATE, dateE, 120) >= 
              CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), GETDATE(), 112) + '01', 112)

GROUP BY    cat
ORDER BY    groupCount desc, cat
```

Explanation:

```
--Convert your string date column to a date type (yyyy-mm-dd --> 120)
CONVERT(DATE, dateE, 120)

--Convert the current date to yyyymmdd format (style 112) 
--and get the first 6 characters. ie; Year and month
CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), GETDATE(), 112) 

--Add `'01'` to the `yyyymm` and convert back to a date type
CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), GETDATE(), 112) + '01', 112)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you explain the Where line ?

Comment: If I need the same for the current and the previous three months (separately), can I achieve this within one stored procedure ?

Comment: Your predicate is not sargable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations - these are great ! Can you help me with my second question as well ?

Comment: If you need previous 3 months, replace `GETDATE()` with `DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE())`

Comment: Thanks. I would need the above ranking separate for each of these months so can I add several SELECTS and just give them a name using AS etc. ?

Comment: Not clear what you mean, do you need to get the month number in a separate column?

Comment: Sorry. The above sp gives me a ranking by cat for this month which is perfect. I just need the same ranking for each of the previous three months as well and want to avoid using four separate stored procedures so I thought I could combine several Selects in one.

Comment: Okay, there are several ways to do that. You can pass another parameter to the sp say (`@AddMonths int`) and pass 0 for current, -1 for previous, -2 for 2 months before etc. and replace `GETDATE()` with `DATEADD(month, @AddMonths, GETDATE())`.

Comment: Never mind. I figured that out myself. Thanks again for the great help !

Answer (score 2):

Try with this for the date expression:

```
...where dateE LIKE convert(varchar (7), GETDATE(), 20) + '%'
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The below is more what I am looking for in this case.

Comment: The better answer. Your predicate is sargabe. But you can simplify you like expression. `convert(varchar(7), GETDATE(), 20)`

Comment: Dates should be compared as dates not as strings. Not a good practice.

Comment: @Kaf At first, Dates must kept as date.